# PHP regex accepts only letters and numbers and only one dot

Tags: php, regex

I don't know much about regex and I'm trying to create a username string accepts only English letters and numbers and only one dot.

I have this regex code:

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $username)){
    $error = "Invalid Username";
}
```

this code allowed me to have only English letters and number, I want to add dots to this code, and accept only one dot.

Comment: Is the dot optional? Can you have zero dots?

Comment: @KodosJohnson yes it's optional

Comment: I think I'd just use `if(!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]*\.?[a-z\d]*$/i', $username)) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one dot, but anywhere in the string? I'd make that a second check:

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/', $username) || substr_count($username, '.') > 1){
    $error = "Invalid Username";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a lookahead assertion in order to confirm it:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?!(?>[^.]*\.){2})[A-Za-z0-9\.]+$/', $username)) {
    // username accepted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` approach:

```
$error = '';
if (!preg_match('/^(\.[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9]*))$/i', $username)) {
    $error = "Invalid Username";
}

if ($error) echo $error;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
if (!preg_match('~^[A-Z0-9]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9]*)?$~i', $username))
{
     $error = "Invalid Username";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/vmjg9J) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZP3xW/2). The `[A-Z0-9]` can be replaced with `[[:alnum:]]` to match letters or digits.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]*`  - 0 or more letters or digits
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[A-Z0-9]*` - 0 or more letters or digits
- `)?` - end of the optional group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `~^[A-Z0-9]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9]*)?$~i` handles that situation well.

Comment: this `^[A-Z0-9]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9]*)?$` will also match a single `.` without *English letters and numbers*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That is valid as per the current OP requirements: only letters or digits or 1 dot.

Comment: cite from question: "a username string accepts only English letters **and** numbers **and** only one dot". Anyway, looks like accepted wrong answer OR he have formulated the conditions improperly

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No, [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610646/php-regex-accepts-only-letters-and-numbers-and-only-one-dot#comment82180077_47610646) says the dot is optional, and the negated character class in the OP regex implies the string can be even empty. Anyway, I still believe OP is after `'~^[A-Z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)?$~i'`

Comment: I suppose, that's the case when the answer deserves the question. The question has 2 downvotes fairly. Nevermind ...

Answer (score 0):

This case could be handled very easy by just repeating the pattern around the optional dot.

```
`^[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*$`
```

wrapped up in php

```
if (!preg_match('`^[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*$`', $username)) {
    $error = "Invalid username";
}
```